# The is_layer_visible command returns a 'false' result despite layer being turned on and visible

Tags: qgis, layers, basemap

I am trying to update a text box in a print composer using the expression 'is_layer_visible' to determine whether a specific WMS imagery basemap is switched on in the map layout (i.e. 1986 Historical Imagery). However, whenever I input the expression string is_layer_visible('1986 - Historical Imagery') into the text box I am met with a 'false' result despite it being turned on, not in a specific group and clearly visible within the layout.

Comment: `is_layer_visible()` is not listed as part of the functions supported in Layouts. I don't know any formal solution, you might want to work around this by setting a keyword/metadata in your layer properties, and use the layer_property()` function that you can access from the Layouts expressions